# Calling a Function once on load, then every interval using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script in a file which gets the timeout value from an inline script, which I do not have the ability to change, only the JS script.

The generated HTML looks something like this, which I cannot control:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script="script-i-have-control-over.js"></script>
    window.statusTimeout="3000";
    </head>
```

So I have this JS function in the `script-i-have-control-over.js`:

```
function getStatus() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (response) {
            var statusValue = JSON.parse(response.data);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = statusValue;
        }
      }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET","/index.php?api_status",true);
    xhttp.send();

    setTimeout(getStatus, window.statusTimeout);

};
getStatus();
```

This function only works after the first execution because window.statusTimeout is undefined on first execution, but then gets the value 3000 on second execution.

I think the problem is the getStatus() call at the end is executed on page load. Further, I want the first call of getStatus() to be able to get the value of window.statusTimeout, and the setTimeout only to fire after the the 3000ms, then every 3000ms.

Currently, getStatus function is executed twice on page load, fails the first time, works the second time then continues to work every 3000ms.

Where am I going wrong? To reiterate, I do not have control over the inline JS in the HTML. I need the AJAX to do its job ASAP on page load too.

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent `setInterval`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica how exactly would setInterval be of any use here? window.statusTimeout would never be available in this case, always returning undefined, therefore the browser continually calls getStatus().

Comment: So call `setInterval` in `DOMContentLoaded` instead of at top-level.

Comment: you made an infinite recursive loop , where you create an infinte new XMLHttpRequest, where  yo only need just one of them...

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't understand what you mean? How can I not do this?

Comment: simply `setInterval( xhttp.send, window.statusTimeout );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `getStatus` is being called as soon as the script is read, which is before `window.statusTimeout` is set.

This will delay the first call to getStatus until the window's load event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', getStatus);
```

That may provide enough time for `window.statusTimeout="3000";` to be evaluated.

Or you could simply change this line:

```
setTimeout(getStatus, window.statusTimeout);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(getStatus, window.statusTimeout || 3000);
```

Comment: "window.addEventListener('load', getStatus);" appears to do the job perfectly - though I am not 100% sure on browser compatibilities just yet.